# Login into Asp.net Web application with Finerprint using asp.net C# Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fingerprint

I want to login to my asp.net web application using fingerprint. That means I don't want to use any login id and password. I just want to login with my fingerprint. I have got a 3m cogent device and the device works fine but I don't know how to integrate the device with my software. I am using ActiveX.

My Javascript code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#scan').click(function () {
            $('#dicscan').addClass('scanning');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#dicscan').removeClass('scanning');
            }, 20 * 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenActiveX() {
        var port = document.getElementById("Comport");
        port.Conopen = 1;
        if (port.error > 0) //Display errors if found
            alert(port.ErrorDescription);
    }

    function Matching() {
        var retval = 0;
        var port = document.getElementById("Comport");
        port.Ksserialnumber = 1;
        port.KsCapture = 1;
        port.KsAuthenticationMatch = 1;
        retval = port.KsMatchretvalue;
        if (retval > 0) {
            alert("Two fingers are Matched...");
            window.open('ResultPage.html', '_self');
        }
        else {
            alert("Finger Not Matched...");
        }
        if (port.error > 0) //Display errors if found
            alert(port.ErrorDescription);
     }
</script>
```

I am getting undefined in port.KsMatchretvalue.

Comment: I have done research about that...but didnt find any clue about integrating the device to my software.Please look at my code..and give me any suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

I am using 3M Cogent CSD 200 model Finger Print reader device 
Hope you have SDK already 
Below is a little code for this device to capture and match details to allow log in .
Two function here 
1.] Capture - to save fingerprint
2.] Match - to match fingetprint at the time of log in
Note : its a code block from my application , you have to made adjustment according to your application

```
byte[] bTemplateDataOne;
        byte[] bTemplateDataTwo;
        byte[] isoTemplateBytes;
        bool ErroFlag = false;
        int nTempltSizeOne;
        int nTempltSizeTwo;
        MMMCogentCSD200APIs csd200Obj = null;
        CSD200Wrapper wr = null; 
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int nRc = -1;
            byte[] fpRawBytes = null;
            int m_Width = 0, m_Height = 0;
            isoTemplateBytes = null;
            int nfiq = 0;

            pictCaptureImg.Image = null;
            pictCaptureImg.Refresh();
            if (true == chkbCaptureOnly.Checked)
            {
                pbClaimed.Image = null;

                pbClaimed.Refresh();

                bTemplateDataOne = null;
                nTempltSizeOne = -1;
                bTemplateDataTwo = null;
                nTempltSizeTwo = -1;
                rbClaimed.Checked = true;


                nRc = csd200Obj.captureFP(30000, ref fpRawBytes, ref m_Width, ref m_Height);
                if (nRc == CSD200APICodes.SUCCESS && fpRawBytes != null)
                {
                    bmp = CreateGreyscaleBitmap(fpRawBytes, m_Width, m_Height);
                    pictCaptureImg.Image = bmp;
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Successful.");
                }
                else if (nRc == CSD200APICodes.ERROR_TIMEOUT)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Timeout");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Failed. ErrorCode: " + nRc);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nRc = csd200Obj.captureFP(30000, ref fpRawBytes, ref m_Width, ref m_Height, ref nfiq, ref isoTemplateBytes);

                if (nRc == CSD200APICodes.SUCCESS && fpRawBytes != null)
                {
                    bmp = CreateGreyscaleBitmap(fpRawBytes, m_Width, m_Height);

                    pictCaptureImg.Image = bmp;

                    if (rbClaimed.Checked == true)
                    {
                        pbClaimed.Image = bmp;
                        if (isoTemplateBytes != null)
                        {
                            bTemplateDataOne = isoTemplateBytes;
                            nTempltSizeOne = isoTemplateBytes.Length;
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Try Again , Some error occured");
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Successful.\n NFIQ: " + nfiq);
                }
                else if (nRc == CSD200APICodes.ERROR_TIMEOUT)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Timeout");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Capture Failed. ErrorCode: " + nRc);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }   
private void btnMatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (bTemplateDataOne != null )
        {
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.Columns.Add("value");
            //for (int i = 0; i < bTemplateDataOne.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            //    dr["value"] = bTemplateDataOne[i];
            //    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            //}
            bool isMatch = false;
            int matched = 0;
            int index = 0; ;
            string strAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            try
            {
                string result1 = Convert.ToBase64String(bTemplateDataOne, 0, bTemplateDataOne.Length);

                string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Biometric,Name,id from Details ", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ad.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();

                if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        bTemplateDataTwo = null;
                        bTemplateDataTwo = Convert.FromBase64String(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                        nTempltSizeTwo = bTemplateDataTwo.Length;

                        //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                        //dt1.Columns.Add("value");
                        //for (int ii = 0; ii < bTemplateDataTwo.Length; ii++)
                        //{
                        //    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
                        //    dr["value"] = bTemplateDataTwo[ii];
                        //    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
                        //}

                        isMatch = csd200Obj.matchTemplates(bTemplateDataOne, bTemplateDataTwo);
                        if (isMatch == true)
                        {
                            index = i;
                            matched++;
                        }

                    }

                    if (matched > 0)
                    {
                        string msg = "Fingers are Matched." + Environment.NewLine;
                        msg += "Welcome: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["Name"];
                        msg +="( id : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["id"] + ")" + Environment.NewLine + "matched value : " + matched;
                        MessageBox.Show(msg);
                        WriteFMRFile(nTempltSizeOne, bTemplateDataOne, strAppPath + "\\One.fmr");
                        WriteFMRFile(nTempltSizeTwo, bTemplateDataTwo, strAppPath + "\\Two.fmr");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not Matched." + Environment.NewLine + "matched value : " + matched);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no fingerprint saved in the system"+Environment.NewLine+"Register someone first .");
                }
            }
            catch (BioSDK710Exception cgtEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cgtEx.ShowError(), "CogentBioSDK710 Error");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //else if(chkbCaptureOnly.Checked == true && (bTemplateDataOne == null || bTemplateDataTwo == null))
        else if (chkbCaptureOnly.Checked == true && (bTemplateDataOne == null))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please uncheck 'Capture Only' and recapture.", "Warning");
        }
        //else if (chkbCaptureOnly.Checked == false && (bTemplateDataOne == null || bTemplateDataTwo == null))
        else if (chkbCaptureOnly.Checked == false && (bTemplateDataOne == null))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please capture fingerprints.", "Warning");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I dont't have SDKS.where can i get them.? I didnt't receive any CD or documentation  with my Device. and can u please give me ur html/asp code..

Comment: Ask your vendor for SDK , if you not able to arrange it than i can provide you the same . My device model no is-  3M cogent CSD200

Comment: And do not forgot to up vote and mark as answer if it answer your question

Comment: No i did not get the SDK's.Can u please provide them.My Device is also 3M Cogent CSD200

Comment: you can contact me on saurabh.tanwer4@gmail.com

Comment: Can you send me the SDK'S please

Comment: yours is a windows application or web Application?

Comment: mine is window app ,but that does not matter . you can adjust the code for web app too