# How can i show captured fingerprint in web application using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, fingerprint

i am trying to integrate Fingerprint scanner with my asp.net Web Application..but iam unable to use the picture box..

```
private void btnInitialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bmp = null;
                pictCaptureImg.Image= bmp;

                if (!csd200Obj.isDeviceConnected())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Connect Device...");
                    return;
                }

                if (!csd200Obj.isDeviceInitialized())
                {
                    int nRc = csd200Obj.initializeScanner();
                    if (nRc != CSD200APICodes.SUCCESS)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("3M Cogent CSD200 scanner initialization failed. Error Code: " + nRc, "3M Cogent CSD200");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Initialization Successful", "3M Cogent CSD200");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Iam getting error at this line pictCaptureImg.Image= bmp; because mine is a web application.Can u please let me know how can i use picture box in asp.net web application and how can i show my captured fingerprints there?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you're trying to access a hardware device from code in ASP.NET, using this as a sample? You are aware that running this code in ASP.NET will run it on the _server_ and not the _client_, right? As in, it will use the fingerprint scanner connected to the server.

Comment: @john I'm with you.... this looks like WinForms code with the MessageBox

Comment: @john yes..Iam trying to do the same u mentioned.

Comment: Mounika, M. Mahdipour's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use client-side code to access fingerprint device. Also you must check what software interface libraries your device provides with it. For example, if it comes with an ActiveX, you should install the ActiveX and use it in your web client code javascript. If it provides plugins for specific browsers, you should use that plugins. Another option (but with security risks) is to use java applet. Please note that accessing hardware from inside web client is restricted by browsers because of security issues. Using different technologies has their restrictions and benefits:

- ActiveX: You are restricted to Internet Explorer only. If your device does not come with an ActiveX library, you can create one in C#. Creating ActiveX in c# is not a complicated job!
- Plugins: If your device does not come with plugin libraries for different browsers, you may write plugins for browsers you want to support. Writing plugin for each browser may be different and specific to each browser.
- Java Applet: You can create a java applet if you can write java code. It is also not a complicated job, because more of the stuff can be done in native libraries.

Comment: i dont have ActiveX

Comment: Can u please help me with this issue..how do i get ActiveX

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas You have to understand: that line of code is not the problem. You are trying to write C# code to do this. In the ASP.NET world, that is _server side_ code. It will _never be able to communicate_ with a fingerprint reader connected to the client machine. Without using something like ActiveX, or a separate application on the client machine, what you want to do is impossible.

Comment: I understand.I wanted to know about Activex and use that instead..i mean where can i get that

Comment: [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) - basically you need a client-side library installed on the browser, in a similar way to how you might install Flash Player, or Silverlight.

Comment: I have tried that..can u please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600978/login-into-asp-net-web-application-with-finerprint-using-asp-net-c-sharp-javascr/44601470?noredirect=1#comment76320063_44601470

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas If your device does not come with an ActiveX library, you can simple create one for you in C#. Creating ActiveX in C# is not a complicated job. Also please note that ActiveX only runs on Internet Explorer. If you plan to support other browsers, you may go for other technologies mentioned above.

Comment: Iam trying the code in IE only...Can you tell me how to Create ActiveX in C#..Have you checked that url..is my code correct?

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas Google for it. There are lots of samples on the web. You should use Windows Forms for creating ActiveX. An start point for you may be https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step

Comment: But i need it for Web Application...Not Windows application...i have tried many solutions..but nothing solved my problem..

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas Yes! I mean when you want to create ActiveX, you should use Windows Forms technology. When ActiveX created, it can be used inside web.

Comment: Hii...I have tried that using ActiveX and everything was going fine but iam unable to download Microsoft Cabinet Software Development Kit. for creation of.cab...can u please help me

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas Mounika, if you need help on this topic, you're better to search on the site for a solution, ... and if not found, ask new question. BTW, you don't necessarily need to create cabinet, you may install and use activex manually.

Comment: i have tried that..There is no relevant solution.I have Posted a new Question

Comment: @MounikaSrinivas I didn't find your new posted question about activex. I don't know why still you're looking for cabarc.exe!!! I told you, you don't need to cabinet files in your work. Give me the link to you question, or a contact address and send your current working project. ... and try to not continue this unrelated-to-topic conversation here!